# Declined Flag, Reason was correct just could take the right

Tags: support, declined-flags

I just flagged a post because it was a duplicate. But because I couldn't flag it as duplicate I marked it as "Other".

1. Why couldn't I flag it as duplicate? (It didn't show me that option)
2. This flag got declined (which I can understand particularly), but at the same time the post got marked as a duplicate.

The Question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146703/redirect-mistake-inside-htaccess

Comment: The flag was declined because you used the wrong type of flag.

Comment: You couldn't flag it as a duplicate because it was closed 2 minutes before you cast your flag. Not seeing the option you wanted is not a good reason to just jump to a custom flag and type it in anyways.

Comment: @animuson In light of the consistent generation of questions regarding this, can it be possible to implement a message that says "This question has already been flagged as blahblahblah?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as why the duplicate wasn't available, the question was already closed when you flagged it.

Now for your other flag, you used a custom moderator flag requesting for a moderator to intervene.  The exact verbiage of your flag was:

> Duplicate of thousends of Questions..

That's great but we are not necessarily experts in php, etc so we are not going to hunt down and try to find a duplicate.

Moderators should only be involved in things that the community **cannot** handle themselves which is not the case here.  A moderator rightly declined your flag.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't noticed that the Post was closed before.

Answer (score 2):

The question was already closed when you opened the flag window.  That's why "duplicate" wasn't available.